# Proper way of copying a Android Java class w. all required resources

Tags: java, android, eclipse, class, resources

Is there a simple way of doing this without having to copy each drawable, layout, library every time I want to copy a class over to a different project?

Answer (score 1):

You could make that project a **library** (right click on the project in Eclipse), and that way you should be able to share that project's resources and classes with your other one.